# RadEditor ExportToPDF not generating PDF in client's environment

Tags: asp.net, telerik, pdf-generation, radeditor, export-to-pdf

We are using the Telerik RadEditor control, specifically for it's ability to render a PDF via the ExportToPDF() method on the control.  We find that this works great in our development and test environments but fails as soon as we get to our client's environment.  What I mean by fails is that typically when you execute the ExportToPDF() method, a dialog box pops up with the name of the PDF file, it's size, and whether you want to open it or save it.  In our client's environment that dialog window appears, but the file size does not appear.  If you save the file, it's a blank document.  The machines / environments are equal in their setup (IIS 6 on Windows server 2003).  The only exception is that our client's machine is in a secure environment with no access to the internet.

We are loading form letters into the control and then creating the PDF once the user clicks a button, so I don't think this is being caused by bad data / invalid characters causing the PDF not to generate.

My questions are: does anyone have experience running the ExportToPDF() command in an environment with no access to the internet?  Could this be a permissions issue?  I can't seem to find documentation on whether the ExportToPDF() functionality uses a temporary directory to write the PDF out to while it's rendering.  It may be as simple as that, but I'm having a hard time researching this issue.

I've also put a try / catch block around the ExportToPDF() method and I know it's not throwing any errors.

We are running an older version of RadEditor - 2009.3.1208 - it runs in a large application with other Telerik tools so upgrading the entire RadControl suite is not trivial (b/c of testing, etc) and is taking some time.

Any suggestions on what to try next / has anyone encountered anything like this with this control?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the export functionality needs an active internet connection. Most likely something in your secured environment is blocking silently the export and it does not simply happen. My recommendation is to check the permissions/processes you have on the user machine and test the same outside of the local environment to compare the results.